# How to run a job multiple times in parallel depending on the pipeline parameter value

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I want to run a job "main_job" N number of times in parallel from a pipeline "main_pipeline" depending upon the parameter N. But I cannot get around jenkins errors where it allows "for" loop in script blocks but not in "parallel" blocks.

I have tried using all the mixture of script/parallel/stage blocks.

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage("All jobs") {
      parallel {
        script {
          def numJobs = "${N}" as Integer
          for(def curJob=1; curJob<=numJobs; i++) {
            def param = "JOB-" + curJob
            script {
              build (job: "main_job",
                     parameters: [string(name:"PARAM", value:param)])
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Using different combination of script/stage/parallel I am getting different errors regarding which blocks are expected. One example of the error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: xx: Expected a stage @ line xx, column xx.
               script {
               ^

WorkflowScript: xx: Expected one of "steps", "stages", or "parallel" for stage "All jobs" @ line xx, column xx.
           stage("All jobs") {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I finally found what I needed to do, basically by trial and error and finding out that `parallel` can be called as a function by passing a dictionary with details for all the jobs to run.

Final code looks like:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        string(
            name: 'N',
            defaultValue:"2",
            description: "The number of jobs to run"
        )
    }
    stages {
    stage("All jobs") {
        steps {
        script {
          def numJobs = "${N}" as Integer
          def allJobs = [:]
          for(def curJob=1; curJob<=numJobs; curJob++) {
            def jobName = "JOB-" + curJob
            allJobs[jobName] =  {
              build (job: "main_job",
                    parameters:
                    [string(name:"PARAM", value:jobName)])
            }
          }
          parallel(allJobs)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```